# terminal/Shell script: how to pass in multiple arguments in one line?

Tags: shell, visual-studio-code, zsh

Say I have three inputs for a C++ file. When I g++ the file and then ./a.out to run it in the terminal. I then need to input the arguments in the terminal of visual studio code.

Usually I have to type in the 1st input and then press enter, then the 2nd input and press enter again, and finally the 3rd one and then press enter.

Is there a way for me to just type everything in one line and let the terminal understand that I just inputed the values for each of my variables?

Below is the code example

so My C++ file has this:

```
int main(){
//number of exams
int n;
std::cin >> n;

//Days of where the exam take place
std::vector<int> examDay;
int examdays;
while(examDay.size() < n ){
    std::cin >> examdays;  
    examDay.push_back(examdays - 1);
}

//Days required to prep exam
std::vector<int> prepDay;
int examprep;
while(prepDay.size() < n ){
    std::cin >> examprep;  
    prepDay.push_back(examprep + 1);
}
```

The above is all the input that I need for my code, now, when I need to run the code to test it I do as follow:

```
g++ {filename}
./a.out
3
5 6 7
3 2 0
```

Is there a way for me to just type 3, 5 6 7, and 3 2 0 in just one line and press enter to test my code?

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: sure, one moment.

Comment: @ Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica I added the essential part for the input of my code

Comment: It looks to me like you can already do exactly what you want right now, with no changes required. What happens when you try doing exactly what you said you want to do?

Comment: I'm not sure I conveyed my question right. So up until now, to input the 3 inputs that I have, I need to type 3 press enter, then type 5 6 7 press enter, and finally type 3 2 0 and press enter. I want to ask if there is a way for to write 3 / 5 6 7/ 3 2 0 in just one line within the terminal once I run ./a.out to just test my code more quickly.

Comment: What happens if you run your program exactly as-is, and you type `3 5 6 7 3 2 0`, just like that, then hit Enter?

Comment: oh it works. damn. alright. didn't expect that. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica answering my question in the above comment section.
Put simply, I just need to type everything in one line.